# binding key shortcuts to shell functions in zsh

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

In zsh, how do I bind a keyboard shortcut to a function?

In other words, how do I translate:

bash:

```
hw(){ echo "hello world"; }
bind -x '"\C-h": hw;'
```

to zsh?

Answer (score 16):

It won't take the functions raw. They need to be wrapped in a "widget" by doing

```
zle -N widgetname funcname
```

The two can have the same name:

```
 zle -N hw{,}
```

Then it's possible to do:

```
bindkey ^h hw
```

, causing `Ctrl+h` to run the `hw` widget which runs the `hw` function.

Comment: It is sufficient to just give the widget name, if it is the same as the function name: `zle -N name`.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me on zsh 5.8.1 on xterm terminal. I have the following defined inside my zshrc to quickly create templates for scripting languages/tests. For instance, a template (of a template) for a shell script:

```
# Function and keybind defined in .zshrc:
create-template (){
cat << EOF > template.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
# Your template goes here ...
EOF
echo "template.sh created"
}

bindkey -s "^E" 'create-template^M'
```